# Smush Featured image constraining in image file that is being loaded on page

Tags: post-thumbnails

I added Smush - what a mistake. Somewhere, it is changing which image is being loaded in the featured image spot, not by image compression but by loading the appending 1024x768.jpg string to the image url. I can't find where to undo this. My mistake was that I also deleted the smush plugin and redownloaded it in attempts to use a setting to adjust this.

`src=https://hackoutdoors.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/ESDC-75-1024x768.jpg`

Previous to installation of the plugin, the size was not being appended to my featured images. Previous articles weren't affected. I changed settings to 2000x2000 from 1024x1024 in the WordPress dashboard.

Markup before:

```
<img width="1024" height="768" src="hackoutdoors.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/…" data-lazy-type="image" data-src="hackoutdoors.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/…" class="attachment-magazine-7-featured size-magazine-7-featured wp-post-image lazy-loaded" ...
```

Markup after:

```
<img width="1024" height="576" src="hackoutdoors.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/…" data-lazy-type="image" data-src="hackoutdoors.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/…" class="attachment-magazine-7-featured size-magazine-7-featured wp-post-image lazy-loaded" srcset="hackoutdoors.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/… 1024w, hackoutdoors.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/… 300w, ..
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, can you provide some code for how you're outputting the image? This url pattern is an indication that you're using built-in WordPress functionality to serve a generated thumbnail size.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Previous to installation of the plugin, the size was not being appended to my featured images. Previous articles weren't affected. I changed settings to 2000x2000 from 1024x1024 in the wordpress dashboard

Comment: After:
<img width="1024" height="576" src="https://hackoutdoors.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Screen-Shot-2019-03-28-at-6.49.29-AM-1024x576.png" data-lazy-type="image" data-src="https://hackoutdoors.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Screen-Shot-2019-03-28-at-6.49.29-AM-1024x576.png" class="attachment-magazine-7-featured size-magazine-7-featured wp-post-image lazy-loaded" srcset="https://hackoutdoors.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Screen-Shot-2019-03-28-at-6.49.29-AM-1024x576.png 1024w, https://hackoutdoors.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Screen-Shot-2019-03-28-at-6.49.29-AM-300x169.png 300w, ...

Comment: Before:
Before:
<img width="1024" height="768" src="https://hackoutdoors.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/990F3132-7031-4B6D-90ED-092B36D74284.jpeg" data-lazy-type="image" data-src="https://hackoutdoors.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/990F3132-7031-4B6D-90ED-092B36D74284.jpeg" class="attachment-magazine-7-featured size-magazine-7-featured wp-post-image lazy-loaded" ...

Comment: Thank you for providing additional information. That is helpful. I've added it to your question.